# CAS - BACK_CHANNEL messaging not working

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

I am using CAS 4.2.3. I have 2 cassified spring security applications. When I do single logout from 1 application, it doesn't logout the other application. According to documentation, the BACK_CHANNEL should POST a message to all the registered application.

However, in my case I am not seeing any messages from CAS in my other application.

I do not see any error message in the CAS logs as well.

Can someone provide directions how to debug this problem better to fix this issue.

I enabled the following in **cas.properties**

```
##
# Single Logout Out Callbacks
#
# To turn off all back channel SLO requests set this to true
slo.callbacks.disabled=false
#
# To send callbacks to endpoints synchronously, set this to false
slo.callbacks.asynchronous=true
```

Adding the following in my cas client **spring.xml**,

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login/*" access="permitAll()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/lib/**" access="permitAll()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER" />
    <sec:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter" />
    <sec:logout logout-success-url="/logout.jsp?service=https://<hostname>/WebApp4/j_spring_cas_security_check" />
</sec:http>

<!-- This filter handles a Single Logout Request from the CAS Server -->
<bean id="singleLogoutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter">
    <property name="artifactParameterName" value="SAMLart"></property>
</bean>

<!-- This filter redirects to the CAS Server to signal Single Logout should be performed -->
<bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="https://<hostname>/cas/logout" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout/cas" />
</bean>
```

And added the following in **web.xml**,

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure SLO is enabled in your configuration, and your application must be prepared to capture that POST and log the user out.

Comment: Can you please help me with specifics how to enable SLO. Is it something that needs to be turned on in cas.properties? I have the SingleSingoutFilter and the listener added to the cas client. Do I need to do anything else from cas client side in order to be prepared to capture the POST request and process it. In the first place, I am not even see anything getting posted in cas client (for other cas registered services) end when I do a /cas/logout

Comment: I updated the description with code that I used to enable SLO.

Comment: I don't know how Spring Security works. To troubleshoot, you need to update CAS logs to DEBUG and see what happens. If you see messages go out, then the rest is on SS.

Comment: In fact, I have enabled the TRACE logs on. I do not see any error messages. I was able to finally make it work by using FRONT_CHANNEL. Although, I would like it to work with BACK_CHANNEL.

Comment: Logs are available in this link, [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599243/cas-single-logoutslo-not-working-cas-4-2-3)